# PHP quiz management software ( iGiveTest free replacement )

Tags: php, open-source

I installed and tested [iGIveTest](http://igivetest.com/) as a way my employer to test employee's, it's a great software, but can't realy use it beacause it's not free and a licence is $370, that's to much for my company. We only use open source software.

***Anyone knows a good web based quiz management software that can be installed on a LAMP (LAPP or for Ruby on Rails) server ?***

There are a lot of quiz scripts out there but I did't find a complete soultion that has some management, test history, reports ...

**Thank you**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would suggest using drupal. Install the [quiz](http://drupal.org/project/quiz) and [views](http://drupal.org/project/views) modules and you can take quizzes and reconstruct the aggregated data however you want to.

Comment: You should be able to call up individual user history, group reports, and anything else through views in a half hour of configuration.

Comment: Installed, it's exactly what I needed, tks.